# How manage migrations after publishing to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using a web app asp.net (.net framework) identity framework published on Azure.

I change the `connectionString` in the `web.config` file with Azure string and all works fine.

I made a simple change in a context and when I send the `get` request, I get this error from PostMan:

> The model backing the 'MYCONTEXTNAME' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database.

When I was working locally I used the commands `Add-Migrations` and `Update-Database` to update the table structure, but in Azure what do I have to do?

How I can fix this issue?

Thank you

G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when there is any change in the DB schema, you need to generate migrations as usual, and then execute them on the Azure database as well.

Generally when we deploy on any environment, Azure here, we use it using scripts and use some tool for example Jenkins to automate this. And for migrations, you can use [migrate.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/migrate-exe) for executing migrations using scripts.

Otherwise you can also execute the migration from within Visual Studio also, as you would do on local environment. However it is not recommended for production instances. Just make sure that the connection string in the startup project is pointing to Azure database and the required firewall setting is configured to allow access from the machine executing the command and the database on Azure.

Comment: How I can check if the required firewall is setting correctly?

Comment: If you are able to connect from the machine to the Azure DB, then we can say that the required firewall is set. Also while configuring the firewall, please open for the minimum required machines that need to connect with the db. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-create-server-level-portal-quickstart

Answer (score 0):

You need to run those migration changes to Azure Database as well.

Take a backup of your database in Azure and Change the connection string in your code and run the migration changes

Go to Package Manager Console and

```
 Run - Update-Database -force
```

Get the script and apply to your azure db

Comment: I think your answer is towards the wrong direction. You should not be able to make changes in production databases like that. Production database should not be accessible from your machine.

Comment: No what i meant was OP should have made the scriot automatically on local when he did the changes

Comment: what i meant to production is that, take a backup of the prod database and run the migration again and get the script

Comment: I tried with the command you post, but it returns me this error: `There is already object named 'MYOBJECT' in the database`

Comment: i think you have already applied the migration on the database